# Magento 2 How can I remove tabs in order view?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, sales-order, tabs

It is able to remove the block by using 
But how can I remove the tab which is added by using argument? Thanks.

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\Creditmemos" name="sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container"/>
<action method="addTab">
                            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_creditmemos</argument>
                            <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container</argument>
</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `removeTab` method:

```
<referenceBlock name="sales_order_creditmemo.grid.container">
    <action method="removeTab">
        <argument name="name" type="xsi:string">order_creditmemos</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <referenceBlock name="sales_order_invoice.grid.container" remove="true"/>
```

you need to override sales_order_view.xml file and place this